# Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42710: type " " already while executing the migration file

Tags: .net-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi, npgsql

I am using Net core 5.0 and Postgress in my development, I am getting the following error
While executing my migration script.

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42710: type "enumtye_emp" already exists
at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.g__ReadMessageLong

Comment: As the error message said, the `enumtye_emp` type already exists, try to change the type with a different name.

Comment: Another thing that can be try is to manual remove the type from database using the following SQL script `DROP TYPE IF EXISTS enumtye_emp;` before executing the update command